# static pointer in C++ inheritance

Tags: c++, pointers, singleton, polymorphism, static-members

I'm getting confused why `p->a()` is calling `B::a()`?. Is there a paragraph somewhere in the C++ documentation/standard that describes this behavior well?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
  public:
  A() { cout << "A ctor" << endl; a_instance = this; }
  static A *get_instance() { return a_instance; }
  static A *a_instance;
  void virtual a() { cout << "From base class" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  B() { cout << "B ctor" << endl; b_instance = this; }
  static B *get_instance() { return b_instance; }
  static B *b_instance;
  void virtual a() { cout << "From derived class" << endl; }
};

A *A::a_instance = 0;
B *B::b_instance = 0;

main()
{
    cout << "Create A" << endl;
    A ab;
    cout << "Create B" << endl;
    B abc;
    B *ptr = B::get_instance();
    A *p = A::get_instance();

    cout << "Called from A object type" << endl;
    if (p) {
       p->a();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create the variable `abc`, `A`'s constructor sets `a_instance` to that instance. Despite `p` being a pointer to an `A`, since the instance is pointing to a `B`, it's correctly calling `B::a()`.

To fix this behaviour, you could use the following:

```
A* A::get_instance()
{
    static A a;
    return &a;
}

B* B::get_instance()
{
    static B b;
    return &b;
}
```

and remove all code that has to do with `a_instance` and `b_instance`.

Comment: @LihO I'm sorry. I wasn't aware that improving an answer using a common technique such as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/2700399) was considered copying. FWIW your answer is much more detailed, and posted while I had the edit window open, as I'm doing other things and working on SO while waiting on some slow tests.

Answer (score 5):

The `B` constructor calls the `A` constructor first. That replaces the `a_instance` that you'd already created.

This chaining of constructors is well defined in the standard. The base is always called first, so that the derived constructor is guaranteed to be working on a valid base object.

Comment: so the `this` in **this** case becomes `B` in the `A` constructor?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you wanted to avoid that - how would you do it?

Comment: @staticx You can't, because type `B` _is_ type `A`.

Comment: I guess you could do something as described here, no? http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/final-classes.html

Comment: @staticx You could, but then you cannot derive from `A` and the entire question becomes moot.

Comment: Looks like @LihO has a fix

Answer (score 4):

What you are experiencing is caused by the design error, which is based on `A`'s constructor initializing the static member using `this`. Body of this constructor is invoked not only when you are creating the instance of `A` but also when you are creating the instance of any of its derived classes:

```
A() { /* ... */ a_instance = this; }
```

So when you create an instance of type `B`, before the body of `B`'s constructor is executed, the body of `A`'s constructor is executed at first - this overwrites member `a_instance` with `this` within a context of instance of type `B`, i.e. it makes `a_instance` to point to this new instance of type `B`.

---

What you could do is to place a static variable inside of the `getInstance` method:

```
class A
{
public:
    static A* getInstance() {
        static A s;                 // <-- instantiated upon first call
        return &s;
    }
    void virtual foo() { std::cout << "From base class" << std::endl; }

protected:
    A() { }                         // <-- protected constructor
    ~A() { }
    A(const A&);                    // <-- protected copy constructor
    A& operator=(const A&);         // <-- protected assignment operator
};
```

then `B`:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    static B* getInstance() {
        static B s;                 // <-- instantiated upon first call
        return &s;
    }
    void virtual foo() { std::cout << "From derived class" << std::endl; }

protected:
    B() { }                         // <-- protected constructor
    ~B() { }
    B(const B&);                    // <-- protected copy constructor
    B& operator=(const B&);         // <-- protected assignment operator
};
```

and possible usage:

```
int main() {
    A::getInstance()->foo();
    B::getInstance()->foo();
}
```

that outputs:

> From base class
>   From derived class

Comment: Outstanding explanation!. Thanks!.

Comment: @JohnX: You're welcome. Note that making copy constructor and assignment operator private ensures that there will be only 1 instance of this class.

Answer (score 2):

`B` constructor invokes `A` constructor...